# 32bit os in 64 bit architecture: difference in calculations?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, 32bit-64bit

I'm currently working on python 3, in particular i'm trying to use the librosa module to compute the mel filtered spectogram in a Raspberry pi 3 model B (with custom linux distribution 32-bit). The code, the data and the parameters used for the computation are exactly the same as the one I use on my PC (Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit). At a first glance, I tought it was a bug by the librosa module running inside the board, so started checking if the functions were giving the same results as in the PC. For this purpose, I debugged the code of the "melspectogram" function (part of Librosa). The code is the following:

```
def melspectrogram(y=None, sr=22050, S=None, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512,
                   power=2.0, **kwargs):

    S, n_fft = _spectrogram(y=y, S=S, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length,
                            power=power)

    # Build a Mel filter
    mel_basis = filters.mel(sr, n_fft, **kwargs)

    return np.dot(mel_basis, S)
```

The functions "_spectrogram" and "filters.mel()" gives the correct result in the Raspberry. The problem seems to be in the numpy dot product, it returns completely wrong results for some indexes. This is a debug view of all the differences between the PC and the board.

```
###### DEBUG START-END: 206-223
                           PC                    BOARD
DIFFERENCE: (48, 11) 0.2191838420044883 != 0.21918384200448832
DIFFERENCE: (48, 15) 19.153408522395306 != 19.15340852239531
DIFFERENCE: (48, 17) 5.670882080544281 != 5.670882080544282
DIFFERENCE: (48, 24) 10.492875862139803 != 10.492875862139805
DIFFERENCE: (48, 25) 12.302969461756339 != 12.30296946175634
DIFFERENCE: (48, 26) 27.631040740403733 != 27.63104074040373
DIFFERENCE: (48, 29) 5.139375749153835 != 5.139375749153836
DIFFERENCE: (48, 34) 7.724733224346115 != 7.7247332243461155
DIFFERENCE: (48, 40) 0.09762231547647067 != 0.09762231547647066
DIFFERENCE: (49, 4) 0.011647182215426476 != 0.023294364430852952
DIFFERENCE: (49, 5) 0.011647182215426476 != 0.023294364430852952
DIFFERENCE: (49, 6) 0.011647182215426476 != 0.023294364430852952
DIFFERENCE: (49, 7) 0.011647182215426476 != 0.023294364430852952
DIFFERENCE: (49, 8) 0.011647182215426476 != 0.023294364430852952
DIFFERENCE: (49, 9) 0.024662982979241885 != 0.03631016519466836
DIFFERENCE: (49, 10) 0.011647182215426476 != 1736.0081098705543
DIFFERENCE: (49, 11) 0.011647182215426476 != 192.99921646614675
DIFFERENCE: (49, 12) 1.2357100597784794 != 1835.7802873745509
DIFFERENCE: (50, 4) 0.01162755916968538 != 0.02325511833937076
DIFFERENCE: (50, 5) 0.01162755916968538 != 0.02325511833937076
DIFFERENCE: (50, 6) 0.01162755916968538 != 0.02325511833937076
DIFFERENCE: (50, 7) 0.01162755916968538 != 0.02325511833937076
DIFFERENCE: (50, 8) 0.01162755916968538 != 0.02325511833937076
DIFFERENCE: (50, 9) 0.05210700691405087 != 333.83850661974526
DIFFERENCE: (50, 10) 0.021008006026422096 != 3965.2472056464244
DIFFERENCE: (50, 11) 0.10780954139916578 != 1530.5278140594276
DIFFERENCE: (50, 12) 0.41251995176336065 != 606.056179725736
DIFFERENCE: (51, 4) 0.011622992280708504 != 0.023245984561417007
DIFFERENCE: (51, 5) 0.011622992280708504 != 0.023245984561417007
DIFFERENCE: (51, 6) 0.011622992280708504 != 69.0566858320545
DIFFERENCE: (51, 7) 0.011622992280708504 != 825.1101267685075
DIFFERENCE: (51, 8) 0.011622992280708504 != 83.02070759794061
DIFFERENCE: (51, 9) 0.011622992280708504 != 931.8205273506092
DIFFERENCE: (51, 10) 0.4501778264666223 != 623.5746140044275
DIFFERENCE: (51, 11) 0.042509683378604 != 1987.8635720924942
DIFFERENCE: (51, 12) 1.884975416295644 != 450.9067305393012
DIFFERENCE: (52, 4) 0.01157539610226416 != 0.02315079220452832
DIFFERENCE: (52, 5) 0.01157539610226416 != 0.02315079220452832
DIFFERENCE: (52, 6) 0.01157539610226416 != 15.369480003003801
DIFFERENCE: (52, 7) 0.01157539610226416 != 183.44230139508068
DIFFERENCE: (52, 8) 0.01157539610226416 != 22.103013355309322
DIFFERENCE: (52, 9) 0.01157539610226416 != 16.947300443667636
DIFFERENCE: (52, 10) 0.7210348336411665 != 0.7326102297434307
DIFFERENCE: (52, 11) 0.07624676888597205 != 38.69928692732359
DIFFERENCE: (52, 12) 1.227613362577455 != 146.59676772956414
DIFFERENCE: (59, 4) 0.011639905409540543 != 0.023279810819081086
DIFFERENCE: (59, 5) 0.011639905409540543 != 0.023279810819081086
DIFFERENCE: (59, 6) 0.011639905409540543 != 0.023279810819081086
DIFFERENCE: (59, 7) 0.011639905409540543 != 0.023279810819081086
DIFFERENCE: (59, 8) 0.011639905409540543 != 0.023279810819081086
DIFFERENCE: (59, 9) 0.015804205007430926 != 0.02744411041697147
DIFFERENCE: (59, 10) 0.011639905409540543 != 4.896282342021101
DIFFERENCE: (59, 11) 0.024309464524604488 != 3.1951156889432926
DIFFERENCE: (59, 12) 0.014833562550355634 != 6.938331348819726
```

The matrix used for the operation are 60x129 and 129x49. I then took only a slice of the matrix (in particular the column 8 of S and lines 48 and 49 for mel_basis), and those are the results:

```
DIFFERENCE: (0, 0) 0.011617925176483229 != 0.011617925176483227
DIFFERENCE: (1, 0) 0.011647182215426474 != 0.011647182215426476
```

Then another try with mel_basis lines 49 and 50, the same s:

```
DIFFERENCE: (0, 0) 0.011647182215426474 != 0.011647182215426476
DIFFERENCE: (1, 0) 0.011627559169685383 != 0.01162755916968538
```

The error, in general, seems to be smaller if we make less calculation.

Finally, just to check, I took the structures S and mel_basis computed by the Raspberry and calculated the dot product in the PC. The results were correct. It makes me think that is something related to hardware and, maybe, related to the floating point, even if this would be strange since the ARM Cortex A53 is fully compliant with the IEEE 754 standard.
Can the 32-bit OS make the difference?

Comment: Your hunch is somewhat correct. The precise nature of floating point operations is more related to cpu then whether it is 32 or 64 bit (which often simply means how big the addressable space is). What may be happening is that those two cpus have different floating point units in terms of precision. In other words: double on x64 does not have to be the same as double on arm. That would also explain why the difference goes bigger with more calculations - cause errors stack. Anyway, without full both cpus spec we won't know for sure.

Comment: On the PC I have an Intel i3.
As I wrote above, I just read that "Floating-point with 80 or 128 bits precision are not available on ARM devices", while, as soon as I understand, Intel has 80 bits precision. So I guess it is kinda correct what are you saying. But so is there a way to make the results similar closer to each other?

Comment: Everything is possible. For example you can reimplement whole floating point calculations (similar to how you extend integer operations to "big" integers). But I don't think there's out of the box solution (meaning you will have to write it) plus the cost will be a dramatic loss of performance. Is the precision you are talking about really necessary?

Comment: I preferred to keep as much precision as possible. I just fixed the problem by casting the "mel_basis" variable to a float (it was a double, s was fine since it was a float). 
By doing this I loss some precision, but in that way there are not anymore those no-sense values.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible problem:

On the PC it depends what kind of floating point hardware your program uses. Native x87 uses internally 80bits extended floats and if the result is not converted and stored after every operation - it will lead to some differences.

The Python interpreter may use different implementations of the float math. It is even posiible to have slightly different results if you compile the same Python interpreter using the same compiler but wit different compile options.

Comment: I just read that "Floating-point with 80 or 128 bits precision are not available on ARM devices" (http://nicolas.limare.net/pro/notes/2014/12/16_math_speed/). I wasn't able to find informations about the ARM floating point precision.
But so the same Python interpreter could use a different implementation of the float math? Is there a way to change it?

Comment: You need to check the source codes. There is no other way.